# Activity not found using Codename One native code for Android

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to install a `.apk` file from my app.

I place `.apk` file to a directory other applications can also access, and afterwards, I call the following code within Android native:

```
private static Activity activity() {
    return com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
}   

public void install(String fileName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(getDownloadPath() + File.separator + fileName), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    activity().startActivity(intent);
}

public String getDownloadPath() {
    return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "myfolder";
}
```

I have also added the following permission to the build hints:

```
<uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Logs also indicate the path, and when I manually browse to that path, the `.apk` is sitting there. I can also manually install it.
The code above, however, gives the following:

```
    D/Instrumentation( 4697): checkStartActivityResult  :Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfolder/MyOtherApp.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }
    D/Instrumentation( 4697): checkStartActivityResult  inent is instance of inent:
    W/dalvikvm( 4697): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f02c08)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3980
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697): Process: com.myapplication.myapp, PID: 4697
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfolder/MyOtherApp.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1660)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3493)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.startActivityForResult(CodenameOneActivity.java:534)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3735)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3703)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.startActivity(CodenameOneActivity.java:540)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at com.myapplication.cn1.application.interfaces.IApplicationNativeImpl.install(IApplicationNativeImpl.java:40)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at com.myapplication.cn1.application.interfaces.IApplicationNativeStub.install(IApplicationNativeStub.java:17)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at com.myapplication.cn1.application.Application.install(Application.java:33)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at com.myapplication.myapp.worker.ApplicationWorker.install(ApplicationWorker.java:68)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at com.myapplication.myapp.ui.component.MenuButton.doApplicationDownloadCallback(MenuButton.java:93)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at com.myapplication.myapp.ui.component.MenuButton.callback(MenuButton.java:78)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at com.myapplication.myapp.worker.ApplicationWorker$1.run(ApplicationWorker.java:59)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 4697):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    W/ActivityManager( 2418):   Force finishing activity com.myapplication.myapp/.MyAppStub
```

The code snippet for installation also successfully works on a raw Android application.

Is there something that I am forgetting to do, or using the activity wrong in CodenameOne?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this line:

```
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(getDownloadPath() + File.separator + fileName), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

It should be:

```
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(getDownloadPath() + File.separator + fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

Reason being that `file:///` gets added in front.

Also, the `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission doesn't seem to be required.

Answer (score 0):

Installing an APK embedded in the app sounds like something that shouldn't be possible and you are getting an error that no activity is available to handle that file.

Comment: Hi,
as explained in the question, it does successfully work on a pure android application. The APK isnt embedded in the app, it is on the device already in a folder other applications may also access it.
This is simply starting the task of installing, which will prompt the user and installation begins. Essentialy 'opening' the apk and have the OS take over from there.

Comment: How did you add the permission to the build hints? Under what hint? Did you use the GUI for that? Are you sure this is the exact location where the file is and that this snippet worked natively with *that path* on *that device* ? Notice that Google changes things like that in retrospect.